# How to draw a transparent line?

Tags: java, jpanel, line, transparency, graphics2d

I am drawing a solid blue line on a JPanel via

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    super.paint(g2);

    if (path.size() >= 2) {
        BasisStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(Config.TILE_SIZE_IN_PIXEL / 3, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL);
        g2.setStroke(stroke);
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        g2.setPaintMode();

        for (int i = 0; i < path.size() - 1; i++) {
            g2.drawLine(path.get(i).x, path.get(i).y, path.get(i + 1).x, path.get(i + 1).y);
        }
    }
}
```

Yet I want this line to be semi-transparent. How do I achieve that?

Comment: For a complete transparent line, just remove the method ;-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is to set the `alpha` for the color of your graphic context:

```
float alpha = 0.5;
Color color = new Color(1, 0, 0, alpha); //Red 
g2.setPaint(color);
```

Alpha ranges between `0.0f` (invisible) to `1.0f` (opaque)

For the long answer with examples, [see this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26349&seqNum=5).